# Ansible test-module corrupting executable before execution

Tags: ansible

I'm working on a  new Ansible module and I would like to use the Ansible [test-module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/hacking/test-module) script to verify it works, as explained [in the official ansible documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_modules.html).

The executable is standalone and it works as expected on its own, but running the Ansible `test-module` on it fails.

I noticed that, before invoking my executable, the Ansible `test-module` does the following:

- It renames the executable into `.ansible_module_generated` (and it places it into my home dir)
- It appends a newline at the end of the executable

My executable is in a compressed format and the appended newline *corrupts* its internal validation. Moreover, the executable requires the original executable name to be preserved, so the renaming is an issue, too.

Is the above behaviour specific to the `test-module` - which means that I can easily tweak the `test-module` script by stripping out the extra newline and by avoiding the renaming operation - or is it a general Ansible behaviour that the test-module is trying to emulate? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Before Ansible runs a module, it will look for lines that import * from ansible.module_utils like the following:

```
from ansible.module_utils.basic import *
```

It will then replace this line with the actual contents of the imported module. This is to avoid shipping multiple files for a module to the target machine. There is more than just the basic module but that is the most common because it includes AnsibleModule which is the helper for parsing args, etc.

test-module must do the same thing in order to test a module. This is done by the internal ModuleReplacer. If the format of your module doesn't support this, I suspect it will always be mangled.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info. Can you give a reference to this? Which part of the code is doing this?